# How to select creator id giving the creator name in an Alfresco share controller

Tags: javascript, alfresco, freemarker, alfresco-share, spring-surf

I need to filter alfresco-issues by "creator name" (and other fields too). Currently the filter form already contains information about `cm:creator` and `cm:modifier` but in order to query the DB you have to specify the relative creator ID. Instead I want to specify the "username" for "creator".

Following the original filter form:

```
<field id="cm:creator" set="normal" mandatory="false">
    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textfield.ftl">
        <control-param name="forceEditable">true</control-param>
        <control-param name="style">width:250px</control-param>
    </control>
</field>
```

I tried both `people-finder.get.html.ftl` and `authority-finder.get.html.ftl` but they are not my case. Following what I tried to do:

```
<field id="dl:issueCreatorFullName" set="normal">
    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/people-finder/authority-finder.get.html.ftl">
        <control-param name="style">width:250px</control-param>
        <control-param name="forceEditable">true</control-param>
    </control>
</field>
```

Does someone have any idea of which controller I could use ?
Any suggestion about how to write a custom-controller if needed ?
There is another solution to do that ? E.G. some kind of association or other cm: object that can refer to the creator name ?

Comment: Alfresco issues, which Share page are you talking about? The My-Tasks page or My-Tasks Dashlets.

Comment: from My Site -> data list (type issues) -> Filter. E.G. http://{host}/share/page/site/{my site}/data-lists?list={node}